# What do you incorporate into a stuffed animal so that it doesn't permanently deform?

Tags: sewing, fabric, stuffing

I have a concern with designing a stuffed toy which is that over time, if stuffing gets displaced from a particular region like an arm or a torso, it will be permanently deformed since the only way to move the stuffing back precisely would be to physically cut it and resew it which I wouldn't be around to do. 
How do I make sure stuffing always stays in place? Or otherwise what other material options are there besides fabric and stuffing?

Comment: What stuffing do you currently use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Compartmentalization**

One way to prevent displacement is by making sure the stuffing cannot move anywhere. If all basic shapes (limbs, head, torso, &c.) are separated from the others by an internal wall or membrane, you will prevent the filling from moving outside their limited volume.

**Use pre-shaped filling**

You can alternatively adapt the stuffing to the final shape of the volume it will occupy.
You will probably have to adjust your technique a little, since this requires adapting the shell fabric around the stuffing, and sewing it in place.
This will have consequences for the tactile qualities of the stuffed toy.